# Override SonarQube automatic branch detection

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, github-actions, sonarqube-scan

SonarQube has the concept of a *main branch* irrespective of its actual name. According to the documentation, the key is *not* to pass the `sonar.branch.name` property to the analysis.

So far, so good. However, when my Gradle build in Github does not set the property, then automatic branch detection kicks in and I get:

> Detected branch/PR in 'GitHub Action' 
> Auto-configuring branch 'develop'

Well, that’s unfortunate, because now `sonar.branch.name` is set to `develop`, and SonarQube will not accept it as the main branch. This `develop` is set as the default branch in Github, but the scanner seems not able to detect this. Automatic detection will not happen when I set the property explicitly, but then of course it is still set to something.

The question is now: Can I skip branch detection in the Sonarscanner without setting `sonar.branch.name`? Can I influence the branch detection so it will correctly detect it is on the default branch?

We are using Github actions in a GitHub Enterprise Server 3.5.5, for reference.

Answer (score 3):

I have an answer that feels more like a work-around, but seems to work. Within SonarQube, I can *rename the main branch*. This is more than just a cosmetic change. I set the value to `develop`, and the next SonarQube analysis with `sonar.branch.name=develop` was accepted as the main branch. This works – for now – but does not seem to be the documented and preferred way.

Comment: I believe this is a correct way to go. Branch name in SQ is meant to reflect SCM branch. Main branch just undergoes different cleanup policy and is the default for displaying and assuming analysis when no branch is provided. However, this should still match the real branch for cases like that, and that's why you have an option to rename the main branch in SQ.

Answer (score 1):

well i faced the same issue, while doing CICD with github action.

i use, this code to get the current branch
`property "sonar.branch.name", System.getenv("BRANCH")`

currentBranch is variable set in github actions

```
        env:
          BRANCH: ${{github.event.pull_request.head.ref}}
```